# Tab should loads data from server first time only

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my react page I am using `Tabs`. On each tab when the user clicks the request goes to the server and fetches the data. I wanted the first time the request should go to the server and fetch the data so if the user comes back to the already visited tab then the data should not load from Server.

How can I achieve this functionality in ReactJS? What hook or property I can use and how?

Comment: Use a useEffect  hook and add tab change as dependency

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please provide any sample example for it or any tutorial about it. I am not sure how to add tab change dependency.

Comment: Need to see how you implemented the tab so that i can provide best resolution  try to create a simple sandbox example and share  the link